# How to send vcf file through MMS in android

Tags: android

I am developing an apps in which user sends a vcf file that is stored in the sd card through MMS feature. Kindly please let me know if there is any kind of api's or library available for MMS as like SMS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have any api for MMS. Just use SMS Manager Services in android. By default the sms will be converted to MMS if you attach image and txt files.